# Update of 15.10 password problems

Tags: password

I have updated to 15.10 successfully, Password not working so remounted drive reset password and got message successful, Started ubuntu again but password still not recognised. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed password for user or for root. If no username specified then `passwd` command changes password for root, you need to specify username, e.g. `passwd joe`. But only after 'chrooting' into system, mount is not enough. Just follow this wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword